# Looking for VB6 online help

Tags: vb6, msdn

I can no longer find the CD that had the MSDN help for VB6, but I have a subscription to MSDN.  The current MSDN library obviously does not have the VB6 online help.

What is the last MSDN library that includes the VB6 help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No wonder you're the 'AngryHacker'.

I believe that was Oct 2001.

Comment: If having to develop VB6 code won't make you angry, I don't know what will.

Comment: Just for the record, this IS available for download from Microsoft for MSDN subscribers.

Answer (score 9):

Also available online on the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032(VS.60).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily download the proper copy of MSDN that works with Visual Basic 6 (VB6) but you need a MSDN subscription to do.  If you have that subscription, here is a step-by-step description of how to find, download, extract, install and test the correct MSDN library that works with VB6 (using the F1 context sensitive help method of VB6 /studio):

http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2014/9/18/finding-downloading-and-installing-msdn-library-for-vb6-on-m.html